# in which protocol the HTTP protocol is inclosed it?

Tags: http, network-protocols

I have a question: in which protocol the HTTP protocol is enclosed in? Why it's necessary, And what are the benefits of this protocol to Http? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you consult your textbook? It's so wild-known that every book about Networking describes this.

Comment: Besides, unless it's directly related to programming or coding, your question would not fit here on [so].